# How do I capture the minimum and maximum for 1000 random integers?

Tags: c#, random, max, min

The problem asks for 1000 iteration of the code.It must allow for whole numbers from 0-100000 and show how many odd numbers were generated during the iterations then show the highest  number and lowest numbers generated. The first part of my code works and shows how many odd numbers were generated however I can not figure out how to capture/edit the smallest and largest numbers that were generated while the code was running.

I have tried many different methods including while loops and my if, else if, conditions. I have placed them through out my program however I am stuck. I know the problem is with the randNum going into the variables and staying there through each iterations without going back to zero.(when I run my code it displays zero for the smallNum and LargeNum.)

here is my work so far

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BissonnetteMessageBox

{
  class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)

      {

        int oddNumCount = 0;
        int smallNum = 0;
        int largeNum = 0;
            Random randNum = new Random();


            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {

                int num = randNum.Next(100000);
                int remain = num % 2;

                if (remain != 0)
                {
                    oddNumCount++;


                }
                if (num < smallNum)
                {
                    num = smallNum;
                }
                else if (num > largeNum)
                {
                    num = largeNum;
                }

            }

            MessageBox.Show("the Number of odd numbers generated: " + oddNumCount +
                "\nSmallest number was: " + smallNum +
                "\nLargerst number was: "+ largeNum , "random number generation results");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the result is when I run my program:

[image]

Comment: Instead of assigning `num` you should assign `smallNum` and `largeNum`

Comment: And starting off with 0 as your smallest number is probably not helpful either. Do some debugging before you post here please.

Comment: You've reversed the assignments for `smallNum` and `largeNum`.

Comment: The integer type has a maximum and minimum possible values aa properties (you can look them up). If you set the initial smallest value to the integer type's maximum value (& the initial biggest value to the int types minimum value), and then watch what happens in a debugger, you should see the two values behave as you expect. By the way, one way to program this to separate the generation of the random numbers from the analysis (max, min, etc). That way you can test the analysis part against a collection of known numbers to see if it works

Comment: Not an answer or for the OP, but... man, questions like this make me love LINQ.  Enumerable.Range(1,1000).Select(x => randNum.Next(1000)) - followed by variables capturing the .Min, .Max, and .Where(x => x % 2).  Replace 20 lines of code with 3.

Answer (score 2):

The lines "num = smallNum;" and "num = largeNum;" are wrong. They should be "smallNum = num;" and "largeNum = num;". That's because the variable (or constant, expression) on the right side of the "=" overwrites the variable on the left side. It's not like in the mathematics, where it can be turned around.
Here is the right code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BissonnetteMessageBox

{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        int oddNumCount = 0;
        int smallNum = 0;
        int largeNum = 0;
        Random randNum = new Random();


        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {

            int num = randNum.Next(100000);
            int remain = num % 2;

            if (remain != 0)
            {
                oddNumCount++;
            }
            if (num < smallNum)
            {
                smallNum = num;
            }
            else if (num > largeNum)
            {
                largeNum = num;
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("the Number of odd numbers generated: " + oddNumCount +
            "\nSmallest number was: " + smallNum +
            "\nLargerst number was: " + largeNum, "random number generation results");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There's still the issue with smallNum, it will always be 0 in this case.

Comment: I was able to get around it by making smallNum=100000 this would allow my program to update everytime the program found a smaller number

Answer (score 1):

A number of people have pointed out the two main issues with the code itself.

I'd like to talk about how to approach issues like this going forward as you learn how to program.

It looks like you're in Visual Studio, programming in C#.  Well, the great news is, Visual Studio makes it really really easy to see what's going on as you step through your program.  You can set a breakpoint in your code, so that when the program reaches that line, it stops - highlighting the line and letting you see what's going on.  From there, you can step forward lines of code, watching as values change.

Here are some helpful places to get started:

- [Using breakpoints in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints)
- [Tips and tricks with the VS debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-tips-and-tricks)
- [Some more tips and tricks with debugging](https://stackify.com/debugging-tips-net/)

This will be *incredibly* valuable going forward.  Because, to be honest, you're not going to like programming very much if you find yourself having to post questions online whenever you run into any sort of snag.  Being able to figure out the snags will make your life *far* more enjoyable  :-)